# Solr partial updates

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Why do solr partial updates require `stored=true` or `docValues=true`? Does solr fetch a document by it's "id" and then merge the updated fields and index it as new document to the open segment? Is the previous "version" of the document then marked as soft deleted?

So, we have a requirement where documents get updated for few fields regularly but most of the fields remain unchanged. In this case, we are having them stored=true/docvalues=true just for the partial updates. We also have another datastore as source of truth for all the documents indexed in solr, so wondering if we can leverage that database at the indexing phase rather than partial updates? This will reduce storage and memory requirements I believe as we avoid accessing the stored files and bringing them from disk to memory and rather that available memory can be better utilised for index files? I am looking for feedback from people on this matter.

Based on knowledge gained from solr documentation and some hands on experience, have a query and looking for community feedback

Comment: "_Does solr fetch a document by it's "id" and then merge the updated fields and index it as new document to the open segment?_": Yes - that's exactly what happens. Indexing is a lossy process (i.e. you can't (usually) generate the original content from the tokens), so you need to have the stored field value to be able to do partial updates (exception: in-place updates where a field only have docvalues for that relevant field). You can also you an external file field if it fits your use case: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/external-files-processes.html

Comment: Thanks, so the only benefit of partial updates is reduced network I/O?  Since so still need to index all the unchanged fields in a document and write to the disk, we don't have any benefit of reduced disk I/O?

Comment: .. and that you don't _have_ to store your Solr data in a secondary location. I still recommend having another service be the source of truth (as in your case) unless there's a good reason for not doing so. Generally this doesn't become an issue unless you're doing a lot of updates to a lot of documents in a crowded collection.